# Can you offer suggestions for this voltage interverting circuit?

Tags: inverter, charge-pump

I have come up with this circuit, mainly through experimenting and trying things out.  It basically inverts Vcc into -Vcc (chiefly for using as a V- for things like op-amps and other such low-power things that require a negative voltage).

Can you think of ways I can improve on it?  One thing I have noticed is it doesn't much like low impedance loads on it - the output voltage across the load drops by a noticeable amount compared with a high impedance load (that may just be me though).

So any way, throw in your thoughts please (or close the question if it's off topic - I won't mind).

[image]

Update:

I just burned my finger on R5, so I have increased it to 1KΩ at the cost of a bit of output voltage...

Comment: I would expect to for example the power in R5 at 5V is 2.5W(\$P = \frac{V^{2}}{R}\$). Did you use a \$\frac{1}{2}\$W resistor?

Comment: @Dean worse... ¼W

Comment: looks perfectly on topic to me...

Comment: @Mark, my idea was suggesting why he burnt his finger with a quick example. Can you explain why you wouldn't see \$V_{cc}\$ on R5?

Comment: @Dean I was thinking backward, i deleted the comment.  You wouldn't see Vcc but closer than my initial thought.  You wouldn't see exactly Vcc due to the voltage drop across the mosfet but that would be relatively low given the current level.

Comment: @Dean This does bring up the largest problem with this topology.  You need R5 to be low to charge C3 fast so you get lower -Vcc and can supply more current but that results in high power dissipation. @Matt Jenkins You could replace R5/Q3 with a complementary pair of fets to solve this issue.  You may still need some current limiting resistance on the high side to avoid damage to the cap/spiking your Vcc supply.

Comment: You have built a charge pump: https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Charge_pump

Comment: You can replace the whole circuit by a 7660 IC (e.g. http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmc7660.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but I don't think this is a great circuit for what you are trying to do.  You said you only need a little power for things like the negative power for opamps.  That shouldn't be more than a few mA unless you're doing something unusual.

I particularly don't like the fact that the square wave driver is passively pulled up.  That won't give you much drive and will waste a lot of power, as you noticed when you burned your finger.

The oscillator isn't great, considering it uses 2 transistors, 4 resistors, and 2 capacitors just to make a basic square save, and then at a somewhat unpredictable frequency.  It's also going to take some power considering the 470 Ohm pullups.  There are easier, more efficient, and more predictable ways to make a square wave just to run a charge pump.  However, in this case it sounds like it's doing it's job well enough and this is not your problem.

Someone else suggested changing Q3/R5 to a totem pole drive.  I disagree with that since driving that will be tricky to prevent both transistors being on at the same time.  There are ways to do that, but I don't recommend it for someone that is coming here to ask basic questions about a charge pump.

Instead, I suggest replacing Q3 and R5 with a complimentary emitter follower.  Use a complimentary pair, like 2N4401/4403 or many others.  The two bases are tied together and driven from the oscillator output.  The two emitters are tied together and are the output that drives C3.  The collector of the NPN goes to Vcc and the collector of the PNP to ground.  That will be basically a impedance buffer for the oscillator output so that it can drive more power.  You'll lose 2 junction drops of voltage in the process, but if you just want a negative opamp supply so that the opamps have headroom at ground output it should be enough.  You can recover some of the lost voltage by changing the two diodes to Schottkeys.

Also as others have said, increase the switching frequency.  The current output of a charge pump is directly proportional to the switching frequency.

One trick I've used a few times in exactly this situation (negative supply for opamp headroom at 0V) is to use a microcontroller oscillator output pin to drive the emitter follower directly.  If you've got a micro in the circuit, this signal is usally available for free or at the cost of using a single pin.  I sometimes use a PIC 10F204 for running a power supply.  These have built in 4MHz oscillators, and the oscillator output pin clocks at 1MHz.  That's perfect for driving the emitter follower pair which then drives the charge pump.

You can see a example of this on page 3 of my USBProg schematic http://www.embedinc.com/products/usbprog/eusb3.pdf.  The PIC is running a switching power supply to make 17V, and GP0 is set up as the 1MHz oscillator/4 output which drives the charge pump in the lower right corner.  In this case I used regular silicon diodes and got -2.2V.  Schottkeys would have yielded a little more, but -2.2V was fine.  Note that the charge pump caps were ceramic.  I really wouldn't use electrolytic in your case, especially if you increase the switching frequency.

Comment: Just tried with a matched pair of transistors (the only ones I had were general amps) - Oh how I love the smell of burning transistors.  Such a sweet sweet smell. ;)  I have ordered some samples of some inverters from Maxim to have a play with - may be somewhat simpler.

Comment: Show a schematic of what you did.  The transistors shouldn't have burned up if you connected them up as emitter followers.  Also, did you decrease the caps?  You shouldn't need anything that big for the purpose you described.

Comment: turns out the transistors weren't quite a matched pair - similar, but not quite - bit of a switching crossover with a large current spike.

Comment: Even if the transistor weren't matched well, there shouldn't be any switching crossover spikes in emitter follower configuraion.  It sounds to me like you don't have things hooked up right.

Comment: I may not have done, it's true - second attempt has worked (but they are still getting quite hot)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't modeled this but i would try higher switching frequencies.  If your not opposed to using a discrete IC you can use a 555 timer or similar to allow easier adjustment of the oscillator frequency.  Then again if you weren't opposed to discrete ICs I assumed you'd just be using an inverting charge pump or something similar in the first place...

You need to fully charge C3 during the high time of the oscillator.  The value of R5 will also come into play here but generally speaking the faster you can charge and discharge C3 the more charge your transferring and the more current you can provide.

You can also move to diodes with lower forward voltage drop, properly rated schottky diodes most likely.  This will reduce voltage drop which has a couple advantages including being closer to a true inversion of Vcc and charging C3 faster by increasing the voltage drop across it when the oscillator is high.  Right now your limited to -(Vcc-2) for your output due to the two diode drops.  This could be reduced to something closer to -(Vcc-1) or lower with schottky diodes.  Note this is a max theoretical value, in practice there are multiple things in this circuit that could limit the actual output voltage.

If your not partial to this topology you can ditch the diodes all together and go with a more common charge pump topology, using transistors and a clock to control the charge/discharge cycling.

> One thing I have noticed is it doesn't
>   much like low impedance loads on it -
>   the output voltage across the load
>   drops by a noticeable amount compared
>   with a high impedance load (that may
>   just be me though).

Of course, you'be built an unregulated supply.  If you require constant voltage you'll need to add a regulator after this inverter.  There is also a limit to how much charge you can push through C3 which limits your output current.

**EDIT-Replacing R5 with a P-Channel FET:**
[image]

This replaces R5 with a complimentary FET.  Ideally Q3/Q4 are matched or complementary pairs.  You can get single packages with both mosfets inside, these have the best matching.  For this application they probably don't need to be perfectly matched unless your planning to really crank up the current.

Its possible that you will still want a small resistor on the high side (source of the p-channel fet) to allow control of the capacitor time constant.  Without any resistor the current spiking on Vcc could be high, only limited by Rd on of the mosfet.  I also don't know what kind of capacitor C3 is but some types could be destroyed by the current spikes without a resistor limiting it.

Comment: The regulator after the inverter is part of the plan (well, 3 of them infact - one for -12V, one for -5V and one for -3.3V - LM337T)

Comment: And I have nothing against ICs - I just don't happen to have anything suitable in my bits box.

Comment: @Matt Jenkins If you want to run three rails off this You need to drastically increase your switching voltage or the size of C3 (while still fully charging it).  Your circuit as it sits today can only provide about 126uA of current at 12V before it will start sagging (assuming C3 is getting fully charged).

Comment: @Mark so what do you suggest I do to increase the current?

Comment: @Matt Jenkins Replace R5 with a P-Channel FET (see my edit).  Then either increase your switching frequency or increase the size of C3 while ensuring that C3 still gets fulling charged during the ON cycle.  If you have some shottky's laying around replace the diodes also.

Comment: Damn, I don't have any P-channel - only N-channel at the moment :(

Comment: Guess I'm looking for an IRF5210 to complement the '3710...?

Comment: @Matt Jenkins I don't know what the exact part number would be, the main things is the switching point(gate voltage) of the transistors.  If the switching points don't match up closely what can happen is that they are both "on" for some, hopefully short, period of time.  This pretty much flat out short circuits your power supply. This problem is sometimes called "shoot through" and more advanced/high power devices have special measures to prevent it, Class D audio amplifier power stages for instance.

Answer (score 0):

In steady state, C4 will have zero average current through it, so your output current is limited by the amount of energy that can be stored on C3 during its charge up period.  When C3 is charging up, the output current will be supplied by C4, and in the other half period C3 must both supply current to the load and replenish the charge on C4.  Half of 166 Hz is 83, and the energy stored on C3 in half a switching period is approximately \$\frac{1}{2}C(V-0.6)^2\$.  Assuming the supply is 5 volts that gives about 20 mW, but half of the energy must go to replenishing C4 so the actual output power available would be about 10 mW.  More than that, and the circuit will no longer be in steady state and the output voltage will start to droop.  To get more power output you'll need to beef up the size of the capacitors, and increase the switching frequency.  Edit: the above also doesn't take into account the effect of the ESR of the capacitors.

Also, R5 is a huge efficiency killer.  You're burning 2.5 watts when the MOSFET is on to supply milliwatts of output power!  You should consider replacing it with a complementary MOSFET instead.

Comment: I'm pretty new to MOSFETs - I'm not sure what you mean by a "complimentary" one.  Could you post a small schematic snippet?

Answer (score 0):

I really don't like the use of a passive pull-up (R5).  I would suggest that you should put a PFET in series with R5, gating it with the same voltage as Q3 (so it switches at the opposite times).  Using an extra transistor would enable R5 to be a lot smaller, thus greatly improving circuit efficiency.

Comment: an easy way to accomplish this is replace R5 and Q3 with a 74HC04, all six gates in parallel for more current handling.

Comment: That's fine if you want to be limited to just 5V for -Vcc - I need at least (most?) -12V which I will then regulate down to (up to?) -12v, -5v and -3.3v.

Comment: Well, I suppose you could use the 4000 series inverter at 12V.  But probably discrete FETs are a better solution.