# -12v supply from +12v

Tags: voltage-regulator, integrated-circuit

Part of my circuit needs -12v. What would be the simplest way to get this, considering I have a +12v supply already available in the circuit? I need ~500ma

I searched for -12v regulators on Mouser, but many of these needed a negative voltage input.

Ideally looking for an IC that can handle this.

Comment: Related: [Obtaining a -3.3v with +3.3v and ground](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/20490/6334)

Comment: Added the current. :)

Comment: Try searching for voltage inverter or voltage converter

Comment: There are 555 timer based inverters but not rated for 500 mA. What you need is a form of 'boost converter'. Use that as a search term.

Comment: You did not mention all avail. Input power sources

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways to get a negative, below ground supply.

- Easiest: If the source is AC, uses a full-wave bridge connected opposite to that of the positive supply.
- If DC only is available, use an inverter that may use

  - a charge pump for low currents or
  - an inductor or transformer for higher currents.

The [Texas Instruments TPS54620](http://www.ti.com/product/TPS54620) is a step-down (buck) converter, which can be configured to provide a voltage *below* ground, e.g. this [circuit from Digikey](http://www.ti.com/product/TPS54620).

An [Analog Devices LT8331](http://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/differences-between-the-uk-converter-and-the-inverting-charge-pump-converter.html) could supply 80 mA at - 12 VDC.

[image: LT8331 -12 VDC supply from http://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/differences-between-the-uk-converter-and-the-inverting-charge-pump-converter.html]

An inverting charge-pump such as the [Microchip TC1044S](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/TC1044S) can 20 mA, if that meet your needs.

It is even possible to use the [555 timer/oscillator to get -12 VDC](http://colourtvservicebbsr.blogspot.com/2016/04/12vdc-negative-voltage-dc-converter-by.html), though regulation would not be good.

[image: 555 Negative Charge Pump from http://colourtvservicebbsr.blogspot.com/2016/04/12vdc-negative-voltage-dc-converter-by.html]

Answer (score 3):

You can leverage the fact that the Buck-Boost Topology is inherently inverting - these are a few examples of [Reference Designs](http://www.ti.com/reference-designs/index.html) that do just that:

---

[PMP7330 - Positive 12V to -12V (0.1A) buck-boost converter](http://www.ti.com/tool/PMP7330) ([Schematic](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/slvrav9)) ([Test Results](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/slvu678))
[image: Positive 12V to -12V (0.1A) buck-boost converter]

---

[PMP7207 - Generic TPS40200 Inverting Buck Boost Reference Design](http://www.ti.com/tool/PMP7207) ([Schematic](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/tidrkr1)) ([Test Results](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/tidubl4))
[image: Generic TPS40200 Inverting Buck Boost Reference Design]

---

[PMP2224 - Buck-boost (-12V @ 0.5A) for the TPS5430](http://www.ti.com/tool/PMP2224) ([Schematic](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/slvr866)) ([Test Results](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/slvr868))

[image: Buck-boost (-12V @ 0.5A) for the TPS5430]

---

- You can find for more Reference Designs here: [Reference Design Library](http://www.ti.com/reference-designs/index.html)
- You can learn more about the Buck-Boost topology here: [Topology Tutorial: What is an Inverting Buck Boost?](https://training.ti.com/topology-tutorial-what-inverting-buck-boost)